# JavaScript function changing value of an attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this line of code which has value of id=**0061237**

```
<a id="DeleteButton" href="#" onclick="DeleteMovie(0061237);" >
    <button  class="btn btn-danger">Delete Movie</button>
</a>
```

When it is passed to a JavaScript function, it is changing its parameter value to **25247**. This is happening with only some values, for other values this is working fine?

The JavaScript function:

```
function DeleteMovie(MovieID) {
    var ConfirmDelete = confirm('Do You Really Want To Delete Movie?');
    if (ConfirmDelete == true)
        location.replace("Delete.php?MovieID="+MovieID);
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You **cannot** have a button inside an anchor. Use CSS if you want an anchor that looks like a button. Use a button if you want something to trigger JavaScript with.

Answer (score 5):

That's because in JavaScript, numbers with leading zeros are treated as octal, and in decimal, your number would convert to 25247.

Try passing it as a string: `onclick="DeleteMovie('0061237');"`

[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types): "Leading 0 (zero) on an integer literal indicates it is in octal."

Comment: thanks, this is what I want :) will accept answer in 4 minutes

Answer (score 2):

try to put id between '0061237'

```
<a id="DeleteButton" href="#" onclick="DeleteMovie('0061237');" >
    <button  class="btn btn-danger">Delete Movie</button>
</a>
function DeleteMovie(MovieID) {
    var ConfirmDelete = confirm('Do You Really Want To Delete Movie?');
    if (ConfirmDelete == true)
        location.replace("Delete.php?MovieID="+MovieID);
}
```